# Visual Studio Crystal Reports on 64 and 32 bit installer (advance installer)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, installation, report, multiplatform

any ideas how to include a cr_runtime_X64 and cr_runtime_X86 on a single visual studio installer?

I can merge the project setup for the two platforms but when it comes to CR as a prerequisite it allows me only one path.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In [advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) I found that all you have to do is to configure the first prerequisite for the 32 or 64 bit workstations, using its launch conditions settings from "Setup Files" tab with the path to the appropriate Runtime.msi and then add a new prerequisite with the path to the other msi for the other workstations.